# Wix: component update does not work as expected

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a shared dll (COM object), we’ll call it Utility.dll that is installed by multiple products. In my WIX file I install Utility.dll as a separate component.

Now I release the new version 2.0 and I use the same component GUID and path. Theoretically his component should ref count, howevever this is not what happended:

1. install product 1 1.0 ( Utility.dll 1.0)
2. install product 2 2.0 ( Utility.dll 2.0)

The Utility.dll on disk is 2.0

1. remove product 1 1.0 and Utility.dll is removed.

The previous installers were authored in InstallShield and the current ones are in Wix3. The Component GUID and path for Utility.dll are the same (double checked).

Answer (score 1):

Look in the verbose log file for the GUID of the `Component`. You should see messages indicating if there are other clients (products) of the `Component` or not. That will explain why uninstalling removes the file.

Comment: It says "Allowing uninstallation of shared component: {Component-GUID}. Other clients exist, but installed to a different location". I guess that Windows believe that the components are installed to different location? But the the final location is the same.

Comment: And that is your answer. Component *is* installed twice but to different locations.

Comment: I am not sure how "different location" is defined by Windows Installer. But the file is installed to the same location. Because the previous installer was done in InstallShield, the names in Directory are not exact the same, but the final path is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same exact problem and the files get uninstalled because the KEYPATH is different between the two components. In my situation, I added a companion file in the newer version of the installer to ensure that the newest text file was installed. Because a file cannot be the KEYPATH and have a companion file I was forced to change the KEYPATH.

You can find the component in the registry by searching for the component GUID's first 8 characters in reverse. That registry folder will have a key for each MSI that installed that GUID and the data field will show the KEYPATH. My guess is that the KEYPATH is different for a machine with version 1.0 vs a machine with 2.0.